# Blender How can I extrude a cylinder outward

Tags: extrude

I am trying to make a bullet casing. Here is an image of what I am trying to make.

[image: The bullet I am using as a template]

If you have a look at the shell, not the bullet, you will see that it is a cone and it has an angle that goes outwards. The cylinder is extruded outwards. How can I make my cylinder extrude outwards with an angle, not just a flat outward extrusion? Thanks.

Comment: Extrude the faces as usual, then select the new edges and move them down

Answer (score 5):

This is a great case for spin modeling. There are two way to do this, you can use the [screw modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/screw.html) (I prefer this way); or you can use the [spin tool](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/spin.html) in edit mode.
I will just describe the process to use the modifier, the modeling it exactly the same for either method; however using the spin tool is destructive (and a little harder to set up).

Start by creating the outline of the shape. This could be done using curves or a mesh object. I used a mesh object, and just extruded a few vertices to make half the shape. Take note of where the object origin is, the origin (highlighted in red) is where the modifier, by default, spins around.
[image: outline of shape ready to be spun]

All that is left to do is add the modifier. The default values work very well, provided you modeled the object around the Z axis. The only setting you need to be sure to turn on is *Calc Order*. That setting makes the normals consistent (sometimes you will then need to then check *Flip* because they will be backwards).
[image: screw modifier]

[image: animated gif of modeling a bulet]

Answer (score 3):

Your object looks like this:

[image: 1]

Extrude your cylinder to the wished length

[image: 2]

Scale your loop to the wished thickness

[image: 3]

Repeat this process until you get the desired result. Some useful shortcuts you might need:

- E to extrude
- S to scale
- Press X, Y, or Z to lock the axis of your operation
- Ctrl+R to add a loop cut
- Alt+RMB on edge to select loop
- Ctrl+E, g for edge slide

Comment: I'd like to add S Shift+X to scale with Y and Z axis locked (all locked except X). Very useful during modeling!