# How to create a rounded cone

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I'm really new to Blender and for my next project I need to create a cone with curved edges. I've searched online and messed around with Blender but I can't find a way. What could I try?

EDIT

Sorry I wasn't clear, what I mean is something like this :

[image: cone]

Comment: Could you provide some reference image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: What is a "*cone with curved edges*"?

Comment: One way to do that is to create profile of the end result and use Screw modifier (or tool in Edit mode), related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47044/create-threaded-drill-bit-from-cone

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39326/modeling-a-bullet and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69753/blender-how-can-i-extrude-a-cylinder-outward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple ways to achieve this:

1. Either Create a regular mesh cone, subdivide lateral edges with <kbd>W</kbd>+ > *Subdivide*, then and scale them horizontally using *Proportional Edit* with <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, or
2. Draw a bezier curve object outlining your cone silhouette, then add a *Screw* modifier to it. This method can also wor if you draw said silhouette with a string of mesh edges.

[image: Bullet]

Answer (score 0):

- Add a cone and enter edit mode  <kbd>tab</kbd> .
- Use loop select to select the bottom edge.
- Now hit  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>b</kbd>  and move the cursor up, this will create a bevel.
- Use the mouse scroll buttom to increase the lines.

See the image below:

[image]