# Trying to make a water droplet, rotate line into 3d object

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude

I'm trying to make a 3d stl of a water droplet (for a 3d printer).  Essentially what I was thinking was to draw out a line like so

```
\
 \ 
  |
 /
```

And then rotate it around the z axis to make a 3d shape.  First, I can't seem to figure out how to do this, second, is that the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90963/how-to-create-a-rounded-cone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a rounded cone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90963/how-to-create-a-rounded-cone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **USING A SPIN TOOL:**

With the pivot point type set to *3D Cursor* snap the cursor to the center of a grid (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) then add a single vertex. In side view create the droplet's profile by extruding the vertex with <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>. Go to the top view and press ***Spin*** button (located in a *Tool Shelf*). Play with the *steps* number.

[image]

- **USING A SCREW MODIFIER**

Select the profile and give it a ***Screw Modifier***. Set the *steps* as you like. This is a better method as it's not destructive for a mesh.

[image]

Comment: The screw modifier was exactly what I needed, thanks!!!