# How to subdivide the lateral edges of a cone

Tags: modeling

When creating a cone in Blender, and you want your cone to be circular, you need to start with a number of vertices defining the circular edge.  If you also want to subdivide into several levels vertically, then you wind up with a huge number of polygons.  In this post:

[How to create a rounded cone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90963/how-to-create-a-rounded-cone)

Duarte subdivides the cone vertically while leaving the circular resolution as is.  In his video, he just magically starts doing so with subdivide.  It's not clear to me how he did that.  Can someone show me how that is done exactly.  Thanks.

Comment: It is shown in the very beginning of that video, first all vertical edges are selected (border select in that case), then Subdivide operator run

Comment: I'm sorry, can you tell me what you mean by 'Subdivide operator run"?   I can't find information about it.  A simple subdivide doesn't work.

Comment: Subdivide operator located in 2.79 under Specials menu (shortcut W). You select vertical edges then execute Subdivide.

Comment: Oh you DID mean a simple Subdivide.  Got it.  Thank you for your help and for taking the time.  I was finally able to duplicate it.