# Adding a curvature to a cone without distortion

Tags: bezier-curves, screw-modifier

I have created a column-like structure by extruding and scaling a circle from the ground up. I would now like to add some curvature to a segment (as seen in magenta), without changing the diameters or locations of the top and bottom circles.

[How to create a rounded cone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90963/how-to-create-a-rounded-cone)How to create a rounded cone provides two solutions to a similar problem; but without such constraint. I have tried using the first method; but I was not able to create a smooth curvature without keeping the circles in place. Using a bevel with a horizontal edge loop didn't work, either.

Is there a way to apply a bezier curve to this segment of the surface radially with this constraint in mind? Should I create this segment separately with bezier with the Screw modifier? Would that give me the precision? Are there any other options?

I am very new to 3D modeling; your input would be very much appreciated.[image]

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions

Comment: Unfortunately I had to include a constraint, which made original question obsolete, which had been marked and closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that bevel doesn't work, why do you say that? Once you've created an horizontal edge loop, scale it, bevel it, play with the parameters in the operator box to get the right amount of segments and the right profile, and it should work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your illustration. I was finally do this right.